Firebase in Qt6 and Qt5
I'm attempting to integrate Firebase into both my Qt6 and Qt5 applications using the Firebase C++ SDK to build a Cloud Messaging application. Despite including all the necessary directories and files in my Qt .pro file, I am still unable to call the required functions.
QAndroidJniEnvironment qjni;
JNIEnv* jni_env = 0;
JavaVM* javaVM = qjni.javaVM();
jint res = javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&jni_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if (res != JNI_OK) {
    // Handle error - could not get JNIEnv
}
QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
firebase::App* app = ::firebase::App::Create(::firebase::AppOptions(), jni_env, activity.object<jobject>());

firebase::messaging::Listener* listener = new MyMessageListener();
firebase::messaging::Initialize(*app, listener)

Errors:
undefined reference to `firebase::messaging::Initialize(firebase::App const&, firebase::messaging::Listener*)'
In function `~MyMessageListener':
    undefined reference to `firebase::messaging::Listener::~Listener()'
In function `Listener':
(.text._ZN8firebase9messaging8ListenerC2Ev[_ZN8firebase9messaging8ListenerC2Ev]+0x4): 
    undefined reference to `vtable for firebase::messaging::Listener'
(.text._ZN8firebase9messaging8ListenerC2Ev[_ZN8firebase9messaging8ListenerC2Ev]+0x8): 
    undefined reference to `vtable for firebase::messaging::Listener'
(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `firebase::g_messaging_initializer'
(.data.rel.ro+0x40): undefined reference to `typeinfo for firebase::messaging::Listener'
(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `firebase::g_messaging_initializer'clang++: 
    error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
make: *** [Makefile:267: libMessagingApplication_arm64-v8a.so] Error 1

I have also ensured that all relevant plugins and dependencies are correctly specified in the build.gradle and gradle.properties files. However, when I run this program in Qt6, I encounter the below error:

:-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras

